# How to use strstrip for parsing a string in two parts

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-kernel

I would like to know hot to parse a string like this "hello world" into "helloworld" using the strstrip kernel function. I am developing a Linux Kernel char device and this functions causes me a Kernel Panic (or Kernel Opss).

The way I'm using this function is the following:

```
char result[100];

strcpy(result, "hello world");
strstrip(result);
strstrip(&result); //Also tried this
strstrip("100+200"); //Also tried this
```

The Kernel error is caused as soon as the strstrip line gets executed. What is the proper way to call this function?

Answer (score 1):

Actually strstrip helps to remove the white spaces at the front. It does not remove all the white spaces with in the string.
Please look at the below example.

```
char result[100];
strcpy(result, "     hello world from stack exchange");
printk("\n before: %s",result);
strcpy(result, strstrip((char*)result));
printk("\n after: %s",result);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, I didn't understand the strstrip() function, this seems to remove correctly the spaces at the start (it removes the spaces at the end too). A possible solution to convert "hello world" into "helloworld" is to use strsep() with the delimiter " " and then apply a strstrip() on each token, then concatenate all string into a single one.

Answer (score 1):

srtstrip() is a wrapper function for strim() (http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.11.2/lib/string.c#L361) in modern kernels.  As it will attempt to modify the string itself, you cannot call it with a static string as you have in the third attempt.

The second attempt you have is passing a pointer to an array variable which is also a pointer.  So you are passing a char** which if you look at the link above you can see is not correct.

The first attempt should not cause a kernel error, but you do not appear to be receiving the return value in a a local variable.  What kind of error are you receiving?  I will update this answer if you can provide that information.

In the end though as Balamurugan A points out, this function does not do what you seem to think it does. strsep() (http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.11.2/lib/string.c#L485) may help you out here but it will only be a stepping stone to removing all spaces. You will actually have to copy the string into a new buffer word by word as there is not way to simply "shift memory contents", as it were.

Comment: Sorry about the poor formatting.  It's hard to do these posts from a smartphone.

Comment: Thanks for the info, the error I'm receiving is a "NULL pointer exception" and something about "Opss", of course I can't copy the code as the error crashes the machine. Anyway, no longer needed, the string "hello world" can be transformed into "helloworld" by iterating through the string copying all characters into a new string except when we find a 0x20 character, which the ascii code of the space.